# Python: Writing lists to .csv file

Tags: python, list, csv

I’m teaching myself programming, using Python as my initial weapon of choice.

I have learnt a few basics and decided to set myself the challenge of asking the user for a list of names, adding the names to a list and then finally writing the names to a `.csv` file.

Below is my code. It works.

My question is what would you do differently, i.e. how could this code be improved for readability and efficiency. Would you approach the situation differently, structure it differently, call different functions? I am interested in, and would appreciate a great deal, the feedback from more experienced programmers.

In particular, I find certain parts clunky; such as having to specify to the user the required format for data entry. If I were to simply request the data (name age location) without the commas however, then each record, when written to `.csv`, would simply end up as one record per cell (Excel) – this is not the desired result.

```
#Requesting user input. 
guestNames = input("Please enter the names of your guests, one at a time.\n"\
    "Once you have finished entering the information, please type the word \"Done\".\n"\
    "Please enter your names in the following format (Name, Age, Location). ").capitalize()

guestList.append(guestNames)

while guestNames.lower() != "done".lower() :
    guestNames = input("Please enter the name of your " + guestNumber[number] + " guest: ").capitalize()
    guestList.append(guestNames)
    number += 1

#Sorting the list. 
guestList.sort()
guestList.remove("Done")

#Creating .csv file. 
guestFile = open("guestList.csv","w")
guestFile.close()

#Writing to file. 
for entries in guestList :
    guestFile = open("guestList.csv","a")
    guestFile.write(entries)
    guestFile.write("\n")
    guestFile.close()
```

Comment: I think you're looking for [codereview.se]

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to write down your demands:

1. Parse the input string according to its structure (whatever) and save results into a list
2. Format the result into CSV-format string
3. write the string to a CSV file

First of all, I would highly recommend you to read the a Python string operation and formatting tutorial like [Google Developer Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/strings). When you understand the basic operation, have a look at [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) to see available string processing methods in Python.

Your logic to write the code is right, but there are two meaningless lines:

1. `while guestNames.lower() != "done".lower()`

It's not necessary to lower "done" since it is already lower-case.

2. `for entries in guestList :
       guestFile = open("guestList.csv","a")`

Here you open and close the questList.csv every loop, which is useless and costly. You could open the file at the beginning, then save all lines with a for loop, and close it at the end.

This is a sample using the same logic and different input format:

```
print('some notification at the beginning')

while true:
    guestNames = input("Please enter the name of your " + guestNumber[number] + " guest: ").capitalize()

    if guestNames == 'Done':
        # Jump out of the loop if user says done
        break
    else:
        # Assume user input 'name age location', replace all space with commas
        guestList.append(guestNames.replace(' ', ','))
        number += 1

guestList.sort()

# the with keyword will close the guestFile at the end
with open("guestList.csv","w") as guestFile:
    guestFile.write('your headers\n')
    for entries in guestList:
        guestFile.write('%s\n' % entries)
```

Be aware that there are many ways to fulfil your demands, with different logics and methodologies.